# Class Mapping Error in repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I'm trying to implement the repository pattern on top of EF Core 5.

I have the repository and its interface defined this way:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    protected readonly DbContext DbContext ;

    public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            return DbContext .Set<TEntity>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Couldn't retrieve entities: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    ....
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}
```

Now I'm trying to create a DataManager in order to instantiate the repository using injection and query the database like the following:

```
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
   protected readonly DataManager dataManager;

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething()
    {
         Repository<MyEntity> entities= dataManager.GetRepository<MyEntity>();
         return Ok(entities.GetAll().Where(w=>w.EntityId>123));
    }
}
```

I've tried to implement the DataManager like the following:

```
public class DataManager : IDisposable 
{

    // keep one EFCore context per instance
    private DbContext ctx;


    public DataManager()
    {
        // create instance of context when DataManager is created
        ctx = new DbContext();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose context if DataManager is disposed
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        ctx.Dispose();
    }

    public Repository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>()
    where TEntity : class
    {
        Repository<TEntity> service = null;

        var RepoName = "AuthenticationServer.Models.Repositories." + typeof(TEntity).Name + "Repository";
        try
        {
            var type = Type.GetType(RepoName);
            service = (Repository<TEntity>)Activator.CreateInstance(type, ctx);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //default generic repo
            service = new Repository<TEntity>(ctx);
        }
        return service;
    }

}
```

But I get the following error on public Repository GetRepository() and TEntity in general:

> TEntity must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
> constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic
> type or method Repository

How can I solve it? *I think I've missed something in the repository pattern*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your type constraints on `Repository<TEntity>`

```
Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
```

Which should match the type constraints on `GetRepository`, but doesn't.

```
public Repository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>()
where TEntity : class
```

Try this:

```
public Repository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>()
where TEntity : class, new()
```

Your code thinks you can call `GetRepository` with a type that doesn't have a parameterless constructor.  But `Repository` itself insists it must.

Comment: Actually this is correct, the problem was in this line: `Repository<TEntity> service = null` (it doesn't compile because of constraints not matching and points to this line of code)

Comment: It works now, thanks to both of you. Now I'm wondering how useful is to have the repository pattern on top of EF Core... Actually I've moved to this pattern only because I don't want the connection string inside the context overriding OnConfiguring, which is deleted everytime I have to redo a DBScaffolding as DB is managed by others

Comment: @Giox Regarding the usefulness of the pattern that's opinionated so I won't comment.  But the _reason_ you're using it might be the basis for another question (and a different way to accomplish what you want).

Comment: @Zer0 Which question? Consider that the application is a WebApi, which will be used in a microservice architecture, so it will never grow up too much, it's not a monolith application. That's the reason why I'm wondering if the introduction of this pattern is worth it.